# A Dream in White, Black, Red, Blue, and Green

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: The puzzle was supposed to be entirely wordless without the plaintext at the bottom, but PSE refused to accept a 0 character count.

Comment: like this? $$$$

Comment: The title compared to the pictures suggest a 5th image to exist :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As noticed by @Ankoganit Image #1

> spells "**communed**" after you take the mirror image of each component.

Image #2

> There is 1 red circle in the middle, 2 next to it, 19 next to those...
> This gives 1-2-19-20-18-1-3-20, which corresponds to "**abstract**".

Image #3 was also solved by @Ankoganit

> and gives the word "**rightist**" by following the line on a qwerty keyboard with the shown letters I, O and Y giving the position on the keyboard.

In image #4

> you follow the line showing with the roman numerals how many letters you go up or down in the alphabets, with the letter I (9) being at the shown position. This gives 19-8-15-21-20-9-14-7 or "**shouting**"

In case there is more to the puzzle, the following could be relevant

> All of the solutions contain two groups of three consecutive letters
>
> **communed** has **cde** and **mno**
> **abstract** has **abc** and **rst**
> **rightist** has **ghi** and **rst**
> **shouting** has **ghi** and **stu**
>
> If we remove these letters from the words (but each letter only once in each word) we are left with
>
> com**mu**ned
> abs**t**r**a**ct
> righ**ti**st
> sh**o**uti**n**g
>
> =**mutation**

Answer (score 13):

### Partial answer

#### Image #1:

> As the symbol at the bottom signifies, we need to flip the individual components horizontally. Doing so yields:
>  [image]
>  ...which reads **COMMUNED**.

#### Image #3:

> Turning it upside down one could read the letters Y,I,O, and their positions match up with a QWERTY keyboard layout. Following the blue path, one can trace out the word **RIGHTIST**.